# How is LED backlight brightness adjusted?

Tags: led, boost, led-strip

I've noticed in a mobile phone when set to a low brightness the voltage output to the LEDs in the screen is 16v but when at full brightness it's around 20v

Now I've always been told current is what controls the brightness of an led, so it's got me a bit confused now.

Are the led strings always receiving full voltage let's say ~20v in this example and the same current, but the boost driver is pulsing differently depending on how bright you want the screen to be?

Comment: Yes, every datasheet from a reputable mfg has a graph of luminous intensity vs forward current. If your seeing 16V at min brightness it's likely varying the drive current not the dutycycle

Comment: How so? By increasing voltage it increases current as well?

Comment: That's correct at full current forward voltage is highest. For current control leds are driven by a current source

Comment: They're driven off a boost circuit too. Is that separate from brightness control or it just controls how much voltage to boost for brightness?

Comment: In general you wouldn't do it separately, if you trace out the schematic you will find a current sense resistor (possible it's integrated on the boost converter IC) the feedback value of the converter is current instead of voltage. Simplest example is how a lm317 is run as a current source

Comment: Ah. No datasheet for the boost ic available. Anyway to know if it's PWM controlled or varying the current only?

Comment: You can measure volts-ac or probe with a scope, with constant current you will have approx constant voltage (mV of ripple swps)

Comment: Measure ac voltage at the boost output?

Comment: Across led string would be most accurate in case it's low or high side switched for PWM ( though I doubt it's being PWM)

Answer (score 1):

You are right. When driving LED with continuous current, brightness depends on the current. But in the era of popularity of cheap microcontrollers it becomes easier to control LEDs with PWM -Pulse Width Modulation. Rough explanation: Diode is powered for very short time, then is off for short time lets say 500 times a second. The brightness depends on how much time the LED is on vs how much time it is off.

Comment: So when it's pulsed on longer or shorter depending on a brighter or dimmer setting, are the LEDs getting full voltage and current just turned on for different intervals?

Comment: Design rules say to drive LED with PWM as you said, full current & voltage. Because your meter shows effective voltage it may seem that it does change. Better would be to look at this voltage with oscilloscope. Then you can confirm it is PWM driving.

Comment: Could it be because it's measuring the average voltage corresponding to the switching on/off period? So for example when set to dimmest setting the leds are being driven on/off quickly so the meter picks up a lower voltage?

Comment: 'average' - this is the word I was talking about. Or depending on your meter can be RMS voltage. When the LED is barely lit then you may have full voltage 'swing', but it is on for let's say 5% of period time, so your voltmeter will show much smaller value than actual amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

The forward voltage of LEDs varies little with current, but it still varies.  There is also likely at least a small resistor in the string of LEDs so that the current can be measured.  If there are multiple strings in parallel, there is also probably some resistance in each string to make the current reasonably uniform between strings.

Consider also that the light output, and therefore the LED current may vary 20:1 or more between full on and dim, and that the voltage is only 20% lower when dim.

What you measured doesn't seem out of line.

Comment: So what exactly determines different level of brightness? Are the led strings always getting same voltage and current but the time duration they're on is what varies?